# JAX WS async client: capture WS-Addressing 202 accepted

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, ws-addressing

I have to invoke several webservices using WS-Addressing.
When invoking a webservice, the ReplyTo is set to a callback endpoint implemented by me.

The client is generated from the target WSDL using async with

```
<enableAsyncMapping>true</enableAsyncMapping>
```

which generates the `Async` version for each webservice with the following signature:

```
javax.xml.ws.Response<SampleWebServiceOutput> sampleWebService(SampleWebServiceInput input)
```

When invoking `sampleWebService` like,

```
Response<SampleWebServiceOutput> response = clientWsPort.sampleWebService(input);
```

if the request is sucessful, the server will return `202 Accepted` however I can't figure out how to get it.

If I use `response.get()`, it will block forever since the response is sent to my callback url (WSA-Addressing Reply To)

Any clues how to know for sure if the server successfully accepted the request ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the response returned when you set a different reply-to address results in a null response, which could explain why it is hanging when you call `response.get()`.
The recommended solution is to use something like `getResponseContext()`, which is called from the binding.

Comment: I will try to use the getContext() of the Response and see what it gives.